# cursor-offset on leave of fill-in

Tags: events, openedge, progress-4gl

openedge 12.2 win64 tty

I have a string of comma separated items that the user fills in manually. Elements have a certain structure, and the chk_store method checks each element for correctness of filling and returns the position of the beginning of the first incorrectly filled element. I want that at the on leave event, if there is an incorrectly filled element in the line, then the cursor will move to the position of the beginning of this element. The problem is that the cursor-offset is not set to the position I need when executing the code below.

```
ON LEAVE OF cfrm-store IN FRAME fmnu
DO:
   DO ON ERROR UNDO, RETURN NO-APPLY:
     ASSIGN cfrm-store.
     icfs = chk_store(cfrm-store).
     IF icfs = 0 THEN
        LEAVE.       
      SELF:CURSOR-OFFSET = icfs.           
      RETURN NO-APPLY.
   END.
END.
```

edit 1.

on leave doesn't work in the console, at least with this syntax, but it works fine in prowin.

```
def var c as c no-undo init '1234567890' FORMAT 'x(20)'
.
DEF VAR d AS c NO-UNDO INIT '1234567890' FORMAT 'x(20)'  .
def button bok auto-go.
def frame f
skip(1)
c
SKIP(1)
d
skip(1)
bok
with view-as dialog-box side-labels.

on leave of c,d in frame f
do:
assign c d.
IF  length(SELF:SCREEN-VALUE) <= 10  THEN
DO:
    
    SELF:CURSOR-OFFSET = length(SELF:SCREEN-VALUE) + 1.
    RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.
end.

display c d with frame f.
enable all with frame f.
wait-for go of frame f.
```

Comment: Your code snippet leaves a lot to the imagination. If you could expand it to a runnable example that demonstrates the problem I would find that helpful.

Comment: would you like to select the text in one fill-in? you can do it with cfrm-store:SET-SELECTION(icfs, -1).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `chk_store` function returns the position of the first incorrect element **in the list**. But to set the cursor position, you need the position of the first incorrect element **in the string**.

See the example below :

```swift
DEFINE VARIABLE list AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE icfs AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE pos  AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

list = "ok,ok,ok,ok,nok,ok,ok".

icfs = LOOKUP("nok",list). /* = 5 : the position in the list */

pos = INDEX(list, ENTRY(icfs,list)). /* = 13 : the position in the string */
```